# Change/Reset standard intent receiver on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, usb, settings

I´ll first describe my problem:
I´m doing some USB-App for Android Tablets which uses an MTP connection to a camera that is plugged into the tablet.
There is one main INTENT fired when a device is plugged in and my app starts after receiving the intent.

So now, "Gallery" on Android also uses this intent. If the user first starts Gallery, it opens an USB connection and I cannot access the device, as it is blocked then (exclusive access).

Now my question:
If the user chooses "Gallery" in the selector that is shown to select the Activity to start (there is Gallery and MyApp) and sets this as DEFAULT, Gallery will start automatically every time the intent is fired. --> My App does not work anymore.

So how can I reset or change the user setting for "Which activity to launch on intent ABC" ??

Comment: Did you try creating your own intents?

Comment: The intent I´m listening for is fired by Android System, so I cannot change it - and even if I get my App started, if Gallery is running, it has exclusive USB access...